# Can't run an executable file in matlab with system(), but it works in command line

Tags: c++, matlab, opencv

I need to run a C++ executable file which uses the OPencv library using the system command in Matlab. I already compile all the code with make and it was successful. When I run the program in command line it works as shown below.

```
lib/sift/bin/siftfeat -x -o tampered1.txt tampered1.jpg
Finding SIFT features... 
Found 2596 features.
```

The problem is when I run it with matlab. The following error happens:

```
>>system('lib/sift/bin/siftfeat -x -o tampered1.txt tampered1.jpg')
  Finding SIFT features...
  Error: unable to load image from tampered1.jpg
  lib/sift/bin/siftfeat -x -o tampered1.txt tampered1.jpg: Aborted
```

The error happens in lib/sift/src/siftfeat.c in the following piece of code:

```
fprintf( stderr, "Finding SIFT features...\n" );
img = cvLoadImage( img_file_name, 1 );
if( ! img )
 fatal_error( "unable to load image from %s", img_file_name );
```

Why does this happen? I mean, if the code runs in command line, why it doesn't run with system Matlab command? doesn't matlab recognize the cvLoadImage function? I am using Matlab R2014a and OPencv-2.4.9. This code was copied from another PC and I just recompiled it. In the original PC in which the code was copied the system command works.

Comment: Do you need to provide the full path to `tampered1.jpg`?

Comment: You are using relative path, what is your current working directory in both cases?

Comment: I don't need to provide the full path to the image because it is in the same path i am executing the matlab system command. I am at the same directory in both cases (command line and Matlab).

Comment: The directory is ~/sift-forensic

Answer (score 1):

You are running the `system()`-cmd in the wrong folder.
While you call your binary with an absolute path, the path to your images are relative.
Therefore, the images need to be in the folder, where matlab executes your `system()`-cmd.
You can simply check this by executing:

```
>> system('pwd')
   "Folder/where/matlab/exec/your/cmd"
```

If the output corresponds to your image location, everything should be fine, otherwise you have to give your program the absolute path like this:

```
>> system('lib/sift/bin/siftfeat -x -o Folder/to/your/txt/tampered1.txt Folder/to/your/image/tampered1.jpg')
```

Comment: The image is in the same folder where I execute the system command. If I run it with the absolute path the same error happens. >> system('lib/sift/bin/siftfeat -x -o ~/sift-forensic/tampered1.txt ~/sift-forensic/tampered.jpg'). If I use both the absolute and relative paths in command line they work. Thanks anyway.

Answer (score -1):

I tried it, and found that using sudo will work.

Comment: This should be a comment, not an answer.